# Put a smaller picture into a bigger one

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

the program-code belows works, but I dont get the results I am looking for.

Code:

```
        using (Bitmap loadedImage = new Bitmap(alleDateien[z]))
        using (Bitmap bigImage = new Bitmap(loadedImage.Width + 3000, loadedImage.Height + 3000)) // 1a) Lese die Pixelanzahl aus
        {
            #region Init

            int bigImageWidth = bigImage.Width;
            int bigImageHeight = bigImage.Height;

            int loadedImageWidth = loadedImage.Width;
            int loadedImageHeight = loadedImage.Height;

            #endregion

            #region Das eine in das andere Bild

            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bigImage);

            int tempX = bigImage.Width / 2 - loadedImage.Width / 2;
            int tempY = bigImage.Height / 2 - loadedImage.Height / 2;

            g.DrawImage(loadedImage, /* x-Position: */tempX, /* y-Position: */tempY);

            #endregion

            #region Speichern

            bigImage.Save(Path.Combine(deleteNewPath, Dateiname(Path.GetFileName(alleDateien[z]), "", beliebigVieleDateien: false, ohneDatum: true)));

            #endregion
        }
```

**But what is this code all about ?**

I want to put a smaller image, into a bigger image(actually building a frame around it)

**What is the result ?**

Sometimes the accuracy, resolution, sharpness or whatever you want to call it ... the quality before merging and after merging the image gets lost, I cant see every detail I would have seen without the merge(when I zoom in).
Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaHWA.jpg).
How to solve this ?

**What should it be ?**

Like the original.[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsPyR.jpg).

**What can I do ?**

Comment: a) make sure all images have the same dpi resolution or use a drawimage overload with two rectangles. (recommended anyway). b) if you blow up an image its crispness will always go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Bitmap(loadedImage.Width + 3000, loadedImage.Height + 3000)
> ```

New image is way too large, over 3000x3000 pixels. It won't fit in your desktop screen so the bitmap viewer has to scale it down. It hasn't lost any resolution. Reduce image size as shown below:

```
Bitmap old_image = new Bitmap("old.bmp");

//border thickneess
int border_thickness = 10;

Bitmap new_image = new Bitmap(
        old_image.Width + border_thickness, old_image.Height + border_thickness);

//draw on new image
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(new_image);

//find the x/y position to put the old image in center
int x = (new_image.Width - old_image.Width) / 2;
int y = (new_image.Height - old_image.Height) / 2;

//draw a border
SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, new_image.Width, new_image.Height);
g.FillRectangle(brush, rect);

//draw old image in to new image
g.DrawImage(old_image, x, y);

//save
new_image.Save("new.bmp");
```